# eclipse cdt not seeing header files in project packages?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to compile a project but I'm getting an error right away that it's not seeing the header files that are in some packages inside the project. Here is a picture, notice that it is not finding the AwarenessMoment.h file, however it is in there.

[image: error]

Here is the output:

```
    **** Build of configuration Debug for project RoyOS ****
    
    make all
    Building file: ../src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.cpp
    Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
    g++ -I/home/igvc/Documents/teamigvc/trunk/RoyOS -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.d" -MT"src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.d" -o"src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.o" "../src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.cpp"
    In file included from ../src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.cpp:8:0:
    ../src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.h:11:29: fatal error: AwarenessMoment.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [src/royos/vision/ImageRecognizer.o] Error 1
```

Anyone know why it's not seeing these header files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely something wrong with the include path given to the compiler.  The preprocessor can't find the header from the source file you are attempting to compile.

I think you could fix this by replacing

`#include "AwarenessMoment.h"`

with

`#include "../sensor/AwarenessMoment.h"`

Either that or alter the compiler include path to include the sensor directory and use:

`#include <AwarenessMoment>`

Comment: Happy to help :).  Nice effort on the screen grab btw.  There should be more of that!